# Позиция курсора

Tags: delphi

Как отследить свойства left и top курсора мышки (на панели)?

Мне нужно например,что бы если **left>250** то **image1.visible:=false;**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если перемещение нужно отслеживать в `TPanel`, то - событие `OnMouseMove`. В обработчик передаются координаты мыши относительно этого `TPanel`.

Если нужны координаты относительно экрана, то есть объект `Mouse`, у него есть свойство `CursorPos: TPoint`.

Плюс, у предка всех визуальных компонентов `TControl` есть методы `ScreenToClient` и `ClientToScreen`. Они дают возможность легко пересчитать координаты относительно экрана в координаты относительно компонента и обратно.

Answer (score 0):

Если мне не изменяет память то OnMouseMove метод панели, во входных параметрах есть x и y - позиция курсора.